# Mutate with Number of occurrences in a data frame - R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame as below. I want to count occurrences of `1` in each row and insert a new column with that information:

```
df1

    Cluster a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 
1      C1    0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1   
2      C2    0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1   
3      C3    0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   
4      C4    0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1   
5      C5    0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
```

I want the results to be as follows:

```
df1

    Cluster a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10  X 
1      C1    0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1  9   
2      C2    0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1  9 
3      C3    0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0  2 
4      C4    0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1  9 
5      C5    0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1  9
```

I prefer use of `mutate` function in `dplyr`

Comment: In base R `df$X <- rowSums(df1[-1])` will work. The -1 removes the first column from the calculation.

Comment: `@ lmo` your suggestion works for the given example, but the answer given by `@Jake Kaupp` is more general as my real data frame consists of several columns with some numeric values as well as `NA`s

Comment: sounds good, @anna. As the question asker, the power of the check mark is yours. Note that `rowSums` has an na.rm argument to remove NA values,  so that part is not a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like using `select_if` inside `rowSums` to generalize the chain.

Edit: If you need to address NA values, use the `na.rm` option in `rowSums`

```
df1 %>% 
   mutate(X = rowSums(select_if(., is.numeric) == 1, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: `@ Jake Kaupp` `@Psidom` In my real data frame I have several `NA` values as well, I need to avoid them when counting 1s. Otherwise my results ended up with value `NA`

Answer (score 1):

May not be general. But this should work for your given case:

```
df1 %>% mutate(X = rowSums(.[-1] == 1))

#  Cluster a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 X
#1      C1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1 9
#2      C2  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1 9
#3      C3  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0 2
#4      C4  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1 9
#5      C5  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1 9
```